# \frac not working

Tags: math-mode, fractions, chemistry, units

I'm new here so bear with me if I don't catch on to something immediately.

I'm trying to write some script for some copyediting I'm doing and it automatically converts the code into the format once you save the edit (LaTeX and MathJax). However, I'm using a seperate cogeditor to prepare the code and it's fighting me on `\frac`. It's confusing me, because it literally runs fine later in the code, but the first time it's used it fights me. What's going on?

```
C_{3} H_{8(g)} + 5O_{2(g)}  \longrightarrow  3CO{2(g)} + 4H_{2}O_{(l)}

\vspace{10pt}

 \Delta H_{rxn} =  \Sigma n \Delta H_{f \hspace{5pt} products} -  \Sigma  m \Delta H_{f\hspace{5pt} reactants} 

\vspace{10pt}

test line

 \frac{kJ}{mol} 

test line


\vspace{10pt}

(-2220.1\frac{kJ}{mol}) \hspace{3pt}= \hspace{3pt}[(3 mol \hspace{3pt} \times\hspace{3pt} -393.5\frac{kJ}{mol}) + (4 mol \hspace{3pt} \times \hspace{3pt} -285.8\frac{kJ}{mol})] - [(1 mol  \hspace{3pt}\times \hspace{3pt} ∆Hf C3H8) + (5 mol\hspace{3pt}  \times \hspace{3pt} 0\frac{kJ}{mol})]

\vspace{10pt}

-2220.1\frac{kJ}{mol} \hspace{3pt}= \hspace{3pt} (-2321.7\frac{kJ}{mol})\hspace{3pt} -\hspace{3pt} ( \Delta H_{f\hspace{3pt} C_{3}H_{8}})

\vspace{10pt}

 \Delta H_{f\hspace{3pt} C_{3}H_{8}} \hspace{3pt}= \hspace{3pt} -103.6\frac{kJ}{mol}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think, this is how `\frac` is meant to be used. you should use `siunitx`-package for the units.

Comment: I was using \frac because http://www.sciweavers.org/free-online-latex-equation-editor this automatically used it.

Comment: @DaddyLeibniz: This is a proof that such online editors are not really well-designed :-(

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Exactly. I just hopped into an editing project not long ago and if I want continued work (which I WANT and NEED the it and the money from it), I gotta figure out how to incorporate LaTeX and incorporate it fast. Does anybody know of any editors they recommend?

Comment: @DaddyLeibniz: Does anybody?  Do you want to indicate anybody is using such quirk stuff?

Comment: As in, do you know any better editors than the one I linked?

Comment: @DaddyLeibniz: Yes: Use `emacs` or (if really needed) `vi` and type the equations ;-) I wonder how most of us learned LaTeX without using such editors ;-)

Comment: I'm familiar with Python and Java, but it's been years since I was really deep into either. When I started this project and started inquiring about LaTeX, the results made it seem so awesome. But having to literally program in whitespace will be the death of me. RIP me.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: What do you mean, @samcarter? All of this goes inline with the rest of the item I'm editing, so we don't deal with packages or documentclass or anything. I actually know nothing about LaTeX packages and such, so I'm not sure how I can help you help me.

Comment: Where do all these horizontal rules come from?

Comment: When it compiled, I didn't like how crowded the operations were to the terms in the equations, and this was the only thing I knew to format it and give whitespace. Do you have another suggestion, @Bernard! I'm absolutely all ears if so!

Comment: @DaddyLeibniz Than it will require a crystal ball in order to help. Because pasting it into an empty document the output looks different.

Comment: I do have suggestions (requiring packages), but I don't understand how your code  produces these rules. Also what is `(g)` for, semantically?

Comment: Heureka! If the code snipped is compiled outside of math environment and all error messages are ignored, the broken fragment of a pdf file looks like this

Comment: @DaddyLeibniz So I guess the answer is "put your code inside math mode", but please take half an hour and read some basic latex intro. It will save you a tremendous amount of debugging-time in the future!

Comment: @samcarter If you look up in the comments, I linked the editor I'm using. Once you take the text I posted in the beginning and plug it in there, you'll see the output I received in a .jpg format.

Comment: @Bernard (g) is gaseous form in chemistry

Comment: @samcarter Where can I find a latex intro? What do you recommend? I'm very new to this language and pretty lost about all of it, to be honest.

Comment: And `(l)` is for ‘liquid’, I guess. Is this standard notation (I mean, as a subscript, next to the number of atoms)?

Comment: You can make you choice [here](http://tug.org/interest.html#latextutorials).

Comment: @Bernard I've seen it presented as a subscript to the element as well as following the molecule in the chemical equation. So I'm not sure if there's a standard for it's placement or not.

Answer (score 9):

The following example uses specialized packages for the different tasks:

- `mhchem` for easier input and typesetting of chemical formulas.
- `siunitx` for setting units, numbers and numbers with units.
  There are many configuration options.
- `amsmath` for more advanced features in the area of mathematical
  typesetting.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{per-mode=fraction}

\DeclareSIUnit{\kJm}{\kilo\joule\per\mol}

\begin{document}
\ce{C3H8_{(g)} + 5O2_{(g)} -> 3CO2_{(g)} + 4H_2O_{(l)}}

\vspace{10pt}

\[
  \Delta H_{\text{rxn}} =  \sum_n \Delta H_{\!f\,\text{products}}
  - \sum_m \Delta H_{\!f\,\text{reactants}}
\]

\vspace{10pt}

test line

per-mode=fraction: \si{\kilo\joule\per\mol}

per-mode=symbol: \si[per-mode=symbol]{\kilo\joule\per\mol}

per-mode=reciprocal: \si[per-mode=reciprocal]{\kilo\joule\per\mol}

\vspace{10pt}

\begin{align*}
  \SI{-2220.1}{\kJm}
  ={}& \left[ \SI{3}{\mol} \times \Bigl(\SI{-393.5}{\kJm}\Bigr)
         + \SI{4}{\mol} \times \Bigl(\SI{-285.8}{\kJm}\Bigr)
       \right]
  \\
  &  - \left[ \SI{1}{\mol} \times \Delta H_{\!f\,\ce{C3H8}}
        + \SI{5}{\mol} \times \SI{0}{\kJm}
       \right]
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: That's incredible! I like this so much. Once I can vote you up, I will. Thanks! I just downloaded a TeX editor, so once I figure that out, I'll throw this in and fool with it a little more!

Comment: Maybe the `\Sigma` should be `\sum` signs

Comment: Perhaps the final broken equation would look better with the `multlined` environment, don't you think?

Comment: @Bernard There are many ways. I wanted the summands aligned after the equals sign (an alternative approach: `\begin{aligned}[t]&...\\&...\end{aligned}`).

Comment: It's probably a matter of personal choice. I tend to emphasize the fact the second line is the `end` of a formula.